# Is Genshiken Second Generation a remake?

Tags: genshiken

i recently got this Prinny Bomb from NISA

[Prinny Bomb Vol 502](http://www.nisamerica.com/index.php?nav=n&article=pbomb/PrinnyBomb_Vol502.html)

under the Nyaruko Crawling with Love image there's one talking about the pre-order for *Genshiken Second Generation*.

Now i've been seeing NISA's Prinny Bombs talk about *Genshiken* airing on Crunchy Roll and have been waiting to see if NISA would release it on DVD however i am wondering if Genshiken Second Generation is a remake for DVD/BluRay or if it is a second season? as i have never seen Genshiken on NISA's store before (and what NISA has on store for anime RightStuf has)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Genshiken Second Generation is actually a direct sequel to the original Genshiken. There's also a manga version which is available in English from Kodansha USA. The story follows the club under Ogiue's presidency after everyone else graduates other than Ogiue, Ohno, and Kuchiki. Susannah moves to Japan and joins, and they also recruit three new candidates: fujoshi Rika Yoshitake and Mirai Yajima, and crossdresser Kenjiro Hato. The other original Genshiken members also appear occasionally. There's a pretty big subplot about Hato and Madarame.

[Genshiken 2 on Anime News Network.](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=15288)

[The Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genshiken#Characters), which discusses the new characters.